# How to use ggplot to plot probability densities?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am looking for the ggplot way to plot a probability density function (or any function). I used to use the old `plot()` function in R to do this. For example, to plot a beta distribution with `alpha=1` and `beta=1` (uniform):

```
x <- seq(0,1,length=100)
db <- dbeta(x, 1, 1)
plot(x, db, type='l')
```

How can I do it in ggplot?

Answer (score 9):

```
library(ggplot2)
x <- seq(0,1,length=100)
db <- dbeta(x, 1, 1)
```

You can use the qplot function within ggplot2 to make a quick plot

```
qplot(x, db, geom="line")
```

or you can add a geom_line layer to a ggplot

```
ggplot() + geom_line(aes(x,db))
```

Comment: Did you mean `require(ggplot2)` or `library(ggplot2)` in the first line of your answer?

Answer (score 9):

ggplot2 has a `stat_function()` function to superimpose a function on a plot in much the same way as `curve()` does. I struggled a little bit to get this to work without generating the data until I realised how to use the variables produced by the statistic --- here `..y..`. The following is similar to what you would get with `curve(dbeta(x, shape1 = 2, shape2 = 2), col = "red")`:

```
require(ggplot2)
x <- seq(0, 1, len = 100)
p <- qplot(x, geom = "blank")
stat <- stat_function(aes(x = x, y = ..y..), fun = dbeta, colour="red", n = 100,
                      args = list(shape1 = 2, shape2 = 2))
p + stat
```

Comment: This code now gives error ```Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (1): x
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred. ```

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Oh right; I recall someone (Claus Wilke?) working on `stat_function()` stuff recently. When I'm back at a proper computer I'll take a look and update this.